# Search proposals within a category

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, search

Can we have an Advanced Super Ninja Search Option on Area 51 to search by category?

It would be nice to be able to do something like `closed:0 category:technology` to see all the open Technology proposals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [implemented](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search). You can now include "category:technology", for example, in your search query.